# How many surjective functions $f: X \to \{1,...,j\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

How many surjective functions $f: X \to \{1,...,j\}, |X|=j \cdot k.$ can be defined if they must satisfy:

$$
|\{x\in X: f(x)=r\}|=|\{x\in X: f(x)=s\} \forall r,s\in \{1,...,j\}
$$

My attempt:

From the condition we have

$|\{x\in X: f(x)=1\}|=|\{x\in X: f(x)=2\}|=...=|\{x\in X: f(x)=j\}|$

These are disjoint sets and the union of these sets form $X$, so:

$$\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq j}\{x\in X: f(x)=i\}=X \implies \left|\bigcup_{1\leq i \leq j}\{x\in X: f(x)=i\} \right|=|X|=j\cdot k $$

And also:

$$
\left | \bigcup_{1\leq i \leq j}\{x\in X: f(x)=i\} \right |= j\cdot | \{x\in X: f(x)=1 \}|=j\cdot k
$$

From this I conclude that $|\{x\in X: f(x)=i \}|=k ,\forall i\in \{1,...,j\}$.

Now all that's left is to choose the $k$ $x$'s for each $f(x)=i$, here's were I had troubles:

I concluded that the total number of functions was $(k\cdot j)!$ but I couldn't really justify it rigorously. Any suggestions?

Comment: so $k!$ multiplied by the number of paritions of a set $X$ with $kj$ elements into $k$ equal parts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is right. We need to choose the $x$ such that $f(x)=i$, for all $i$ from $1$ to $j$. The number of ways to do this choosing is the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{jk}{k,k,k,\dots,k}.$$
This is equal to $\frac{(jk)!}{(k!)^j}$.

A slower way of doing the same thing is to note that there are $\binom{jk}{k}$ ways to choose the $x$ such that $f(x)=1$. For each of these ways there are $\binom{jk-k}{k}$ ways to choose where $2$ goes, and so on. When we multiply these binomial coefficients and simplify, we get $\frac{(jk)!}{(k!)^j}$.

Comment: Hmm, then my answer is wrong, right? because I found there were $(jk)!$ and you got $\frac {(jk)!}{(k!)^j}$. I don't get what I did wrong...

Comment: Oh I see where I screwed up! When choosing, for example, the x's for $f(x)=1$ the order doesn't matter, and I was counting them as if it did.

Comment: Your *analysis* was completely right. The only problem was the counting at the very end. You can verify the incorrectness of $(jk)!$ by hand-listing all possibilities for some very small $j$ and $k$, most trivially $j=1$ and $k=2$., or $j=k=2$.  And the reason you describe in the previous comment is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much I Andre! I could get the right result, however, when I did the simplication leading to $\frac {(jk)!}{(k!)^j}$ I had obviate a lot of terms in between the first and last combinations, how can I prove that  $\frac {(jk)!}{(k!)^j}$ is in fact the result of that product? Induction?

Comment: In principle induction. In practice, write down the product of the first few binomial coefficients, and the pattern is clear. We get $\frac{(kj)!}{k!(kj-k)!} \cdot \frac{(kj-k)!}{k!(kj-2k)!}\cdot\frac{(kj-2k)!}{k!(kj-3k)!}\cdots$. Note the cancellations.

Comment: I did that and saw the cancellations, it's just that my professors are kind of picky when it comes to stuff like that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another way is to start from your $(jk)!$, and note that we can scramble the numbers in the first group of $k$, the second group of $k$, and so on without changing the function. So to correct for the multiple count we need to divide by $(k!)^j$.